# What is the request line for HTTP/2?

Tags: http2, requestheader

For HTTP/0.9:

```
GET /
```

For HTTP/1.0:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
```

For HTTP/1.1:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

What is the request line for HTTP/2?
Is it something like:

```
GET / HTTP/2.0
```

Or HTTP/2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither; there is not such request line, because HTTP/2 ([RFC 7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540)) does not use lines but frames ([section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-4)) for communication. Inside those frames, headers are exchanged using HTTP header fields ([section 8.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2)).

The client must first know whether the server supports HTTP/2.

- For HTTP ([section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-3.2)), this is done with `Upgrade: h2c` headers:

  ```
  > GET / HTTP/1.1
  > Host: server.example.com
  > Connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings
  > Upgrade: h2c
  > HTTP2-Settings: <base64url encoding of HTTP/2 SETTINGS payload>
  >
  < HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
  < Connection: Upgrade
  < Upgrade: h2c
  <
    [ HTTP/2 connection ...
  ```
- For HTTPS ([section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-3.3)), `h2` *protocol identifier* in TLS-ALPN ([RFC 7301](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7301.html)) is used.
- Immediately start with HTTP/2 *connection preface*, because of *prior knowledge* ([section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-3.4)).

Now, the *HTTP/2 client connection preface* ([section 3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-3.5)) might be the equivalent you are looking for, as the communication always begins with a sequence of 24 octets:

- `0x505249202a20485454502f322e300d0a0d0a534d0d0a0d0a`

  i.e. `PRI *m HTTP/2.0\r\n\r\nSM\r\n\r\n`

After that, the header fields are exchanged in the frames, using *header compression* ([section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-4.3)):

> Header lists are collections of zero or more header fields.  When
> transmitted over a connection, a header list is serialized into a
> header block using HTTP header compression [[COMPRESSION](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7541)].  The
> serialized header block is then divided into one or more octet
> sequences, called header block fragments, and transmitted within the
> payload of `HEADERS` ([Section 6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-6.2)), `PUSH_PROMISE` ([Section 6.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-6.6)), or
> `CONTINUATION` ([Section 6.10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-6.10)) frames.

The HTTP/2 equivalents for several HTTP/1.1 requests and responses are illustrated in the examples on [section 8.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.3), e.g.

> ```
>  GET /resource HTTP/1.1           HEADERS
>  Host: example.org          ==>     + END_STREAM
>  Accept: image/jpeg                 + END_HEADERS
>                                       :method = GET
>                                       :scheme = https
>                                       :path = /resource
>                                       host = example.org
>                                       accept = image/jpeg
> ```